# Redis response time is too much

Tags: php, caching, redis, lumen

I developed an application with Lumen and My-Sql (MariaDB engine) with Redis for the caching.

**The problem:**
I have three Entities: MyEntity, Entitiy1 and Entitiy2.
I want to join MyEntity with Entity1 and Entity2 and hold the result into the Redis for the next usage and increase the response time.

**The code in index action is:**

```
// Used a `test` key for Redis and hold the joined Entity1 and Entity2 to MyEntity
return Cache::rememberForever('test', function () {
     return MyEntity::query()->with(['Entity1','Entity2'])->paginate(700);
});
```

In the first time (When Redis is empty) the response time is about 1000ms

In the second response time (When Redis hold the data) is about 830ms.

I think the response time for the second request is too much, because I used Redis so I expect a quick response.

**What can I do for the above code to reduce the response time?**

If you have a better proposal for this situation, please add comment.